# Spring boot 3 and Swagger ui java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema$AdditionalPropertiesValue additionalProperties()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, spring-kafka

Hi I'a having and issue with swagger ui after upgrading to spring boot 3. The swagger-ui doesnt work anymore and I got and 404 and "White Label" page as response.

After taking a closer look I need to change
from: implementation(group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.5.8')

to: implementation(group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui', version: '2.0.3')

After that it did work, however in one of my other projects we had an issue with a dependency conflict, so the swagger-ui was throwing a 500 where trying to the fetch the /v3/api-docs/:
between: io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:7.3.1 and springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.3
Those 2 dependencies need to use io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations-jakarta, but with different versions

So in gradle I hat to resolve the conflict to force io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations-jakarta:2.2.8.

Answer (score 8):

in my case, even though I have springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui i also had to add this dependency

mvn

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are upgrading from spring 2 to 3 you have to use:

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.3'// swagger ui / openapi 3.0
```

instead of: `implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.8'`

If the swagger-ui gives you an error with /v3/api-docs/, maybe is because a dependency conflict, so I was able to solve it by forcing a dependency:

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema$AdditionalPropertiesValue io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema.additionalProperties()'
        at io.swagger.v3.core.util.AnnotationsUtils.getSchemaFromAnnotation(AnnotationsUtils.java:552) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at io.swagger.v3.core.util.AnnotationsUtils.getSchema(AnnotationsUtils.java:1170) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.springdoc.core.service.GenericParameterService.setSchema(GenericParameterService.java:323) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
        at org.springdoc.core.service.GenericParameterService.buildParameterFromDoc(GenericParameterService.java:299) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
        at org.springdoc.core.service.AbstractRequestService.build(AbstractRequestService.java:321) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
        at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.calculatePath(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:472) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
        at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.calculatePath(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:652) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
        at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.lambda$calculatePath$11(OpenApiResource.java:219) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
```

Dependency resolution with gradle:

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'io.swagger.core.v3') {
            details.useVersion("2.2.8")
            details.because('Swagger ui and Kafka Avro serializer incoptable dependency io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations')
        }
```

Comment: You are right, I have avro dependency and faced similar issue, by forcing above swagger version, issue resolved for me.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution could be to exclude the swagger-annotations dependency from springdoc-openapi and include a newer version manually

```
//swagger
// exclude swagger annotation and use newer version due conflicts with avro serializer
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0"){
    exclude group: "io.swagger.core.v3", module:"swagger-annotations"
}
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations
implementation 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.15'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Please add these two dependency in pom.xml file it worked for me.

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the above error just ensure that all your dependencies are compatible by using the command `mvn dependency:tree`
In my case `io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models` and `io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations` dependencies version are not compatible with springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui dependency so after changing the version error got resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).